# How to move a given number of random files on Unix/Linux OS

Tags: linux, unix, mv

I'm facing this simple task but, I'm also wondering about what's the easiest and short way to do it.

My proposal is move a given number of random files from a directory to another. This task is part of the creation of two datasets I need for machine learning: a training set and a testing set. My goal is move away 10% of the file from a directory in order to get the dataset against which I could test my categorizer, and obtain a training set from the source directory.

So, what's the most compact typing for this "move n random files" task?

Comment: If your files have a uniform, evenly distrubuted numeric file name pattern, `mv *0 otherdir` would move 10% -- it's not random, but it's evenly distributed, which may even be closer to what you actually want; and, it's easy to document and trivial to reproduce.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not my case, but your suggestion is really good.

Answer (score 70):

Use a combination of `shuf` and `xargs` (it's a good idea to look at their documentation with `man`):

```
shuf -n 10 -e * | xargs -i mv {} path-to-new-folder
```

The command above selects 10 random files of the current folder (the `*` part) and then move them to the new folder.

### Update

Although longer, one might find this version even simpler to understand:

```
ls | shuf -n 10 | xargs -i mv {} path-to-new-folder
```

`shuf` just generates a random permutation of the standard input, limiting the results to 10 (like using `head`, but probably faster).

Comment: The command was tested on Debian/Ubuntu and `shuf`'s version was `8.25`.

Comment: @Mithril I've got the same `-bash: /usr/bin/shuf: Argument list too long` error when folder has too many files (more than 200K in my case).

Comment: @mrwheet, you may try to apply `head -n <N>` or `tail -n <N>` after `ls`, for example. This would produce a shorter list of arguments for `shuf`. Then you repeat the process if it is necessary.

Comment: Great. This helped me. Thanks

Comment: this doesn't work on mac . On mac you have to do `ls | gshuf -n 10 | xargs -I {} mv {} path-to-new-folder`

Comment: @boechat107 I liked the second one as it also works when the argument list is long.

Answer (score 3):

You could use bash random generator that generates an int between 0 and 32767 to choose if a file must be put in set1 or set2.  That would do:

```
for file in ./*; do
  val=$RANDOM
  if test $val -gt 3276; then
    mv "$file" ../set1
  else
    mv "$file" ../set2
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You can shuffle the file list using shuf or sort -R.
But you still need to take a subset, which you
can do with head/tail.

Comment: so `ls $source_dir|sort -R|head -${tobemoved}| xargs -i mv $target_dir/{}` - or something close to that.

Comment: `sort -R` is not supported in all variants of Unix, like for instance OSX.

Answer (score 2):

The question is pretty old, but for the record this works on OSX.

You have to install `gshuf` with `brew install coreutils`, then use:

```
tenpercent=$((`ls | wc -l` * 10/100))

ls | gshuf -n $tenpercent | xargs -I {} mv {} destination/path/
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this with Python. I find this easier.

Here is a python script I use to move a random percent of images that also gets associated label datasets typically required for CV image datasets. Note this moves the files because I do not want my test training dataset in my training dataset.

I use the below for Yolo training sets as labels and images are in the same directory and the labels are txt files.

```
import numpy as np
import os
import random

#set directories
directory = str('/MauiData/maui_complete_sf_train')
target_directory = str('/MauiData/maui_complete_sf_test')
data_set_percent_size = float(0.07)

#print(os.listdir(directory))

# list all files in dir that are an image
files = [f for f in os.listdir(directory) if f.endswith('.jpg')]

#print(files)

# select a percent of the files randomly 
random_files = random.sample(files, int(len(files)*data_set_percent_size))
#random_files = np.random.choice(files, int(len(files)*data_set_percent_size))

#print(random_files)

# move the randomly selected images by renaming directory 

for random_file_name in random_files:      
    #print(directory+'/'+random_file_name)
    #print(target_directory+'/'+random_file_name)
    os.rename(directory+'/'+random_file_name, target_directory+'/'+random_file_name)
    continue

# move the relevant labels for the randomly selected images

for image_labels in random_files:
    # strip extension and add .txt to find corellating label file then rename directory. 
    os.rename(directory+'/'+(os.path.splitext(image_labels)[0]+'.txt'), target_directory+'/'+(os.path.splitext(image_labels)[0]+'.txt'))

    continue
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternative version with `find` to avoid problems with folders.
It copies 31415 randomly chosen files into `/home/user/dir/`

```sh
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | sort -R | head -31415 | xargs cp -t /home/user/dir/
```

Comment: This copies files instead of moving them, so according to the user's needs, this would not separate the dataset to a training and testing set, but correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 0):

Typically, we do this with a python script or a Java program. Either of these can use a proper RNG to make the random decisions, and then invoke the necessary calls to move files around.

Comment: Interesting, so you're suggesting to use a RNG... of course, moving files giving a limit to xarg would not end in a proper random selection. I'll think about it

Comment: How can you possibly achieve 'random' without an RNG?

Comment: Of course, It's not possible. I was just thinking about taking some files from a directory making something like ls | head -20. I suppose that repeating this task hundreds of time agaist the same directory containing hundreds of file, will not be giving always the same results. Am I wrong maybe?

Comment: Would it be considered as good advice using bash random num generator? - you can start from choosing random num of files to be moved, than - you can list files to a tmp.file - and read random lines to get files and move them; `#!/bin/bash

#Get the range
file_list_no=`ls -1 | wc -l`

number=$RANDOM
let "number %= $file_list_no"

echo "Chosing random number of files to be moved: $number of $file_list_no"`

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about bash' random generator. Anyway I need to get a given number of random files.

Comment: ls | head will always be in the same order.

Answer (score 0):

With the zsh shell:

```
mv -- *(oe['REPLY=$RANDOM'][1,10]) /path/to/destination/
```

Where we use the `oe` glob qualifier to `o`rder the glob expansion based on the `e`valuation of the given code (which here returns a random value), and select the first 10.

On recent GNU systems, and with a shell with support for ksh-style process substitution (ksh93, zsh, bash) you can do:

```
xargs -r0a <(ls -U --zero | shuf -zn10) mv -t /path/to/destination --
```

`ls -U --zero` can be replaced with `printf '%s\0' *` is GNU `ls` is too old to support `--zero`. With the difference that if there's no non-hidden file in the current directory, you'll get an error about the failure to move a file called `*`.

```
xargs -r0a <(shuf -zen10 -- *) mv -t /path/to/destination --
```

Could also be used as a more correct/reliable/efficient variation on [@boechat107's answer](/a/23714774), though with the added caveat that you may run into a *Argument list too long* error upon attempting to  execute `shuf` if there's a large number of non-hidden files in the current working directory. The `printf`-based approach above should be fine in that regard as `printf` is generally built in the shells and so not affected by that limitation of the `execve()` system call.

To move 10% as opposed to 10, with zsh:

```
files=(*(Noe['REPLY=$RANDOM']))
mv -- $files[1,$#files/10] /path/to/destination/
```

(10% rounded down).